# Concatenate to each timestamp in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a keras layer which outputs N timestamps of size M (thus NxM size). I want to append the same vector of size 1xK to all time stamps, so the output should have N timestamps of size M+K. If I use the Concatenate layer like this:

```
x = Concatenate()[x, v]
```

It gives an error since the dimensions do not match. And if I use a TimeDistributed wrapper like this:

```
x = TimeDistributed(Concatenate())[x, v]
```

It gives an error since vector v does not have time stamps.

Which is the easiest way of doing this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, duplicate your vector `N` times using `RepeatVector`:

```
v = RepeatVector(N)(v) # shape == (N, K)
```

Then, as their shapes are matching now (`(N, M)` and `(N, K)`), you can concatenate them:

```
x = Concatenate()([x, v]) # shape == (N, M+K)
```

---

If `N` is unknown you can do this manually using the corresponding backend functions in a lambda layer:

```
from keras import backend as K

def func(xv):
    x, v = xv
    n = x.shape[1]
    v = K.repeat(v, n)
    return K.concatenate((x, v))

x = Lambda(lambda xv: func(xv))([x, v])
```

Comment: There is a problem with that solution: the x vector comes fron an Input where the number of timestamps is set to None, since it is variable. This means that the number N passed as an argument to RepeatVector is not a priori known. Is there any way to set it to a variable value?

Comment: @RodrigoSernaPérez some people would argue that this is not a problem with the answer but with the question: you didn't mention this anywhere. However, I updated my answer with an alternative solution. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: yes, I saw the problem after checking your first solution. Thanks!!
Now I saw a second difficulty: what happens if x is a 3D tensor? (batch + temporal variables). It looks like K.repeat only works on 2D matrices.

Comment: @RodrigoSernaPérez you can have a look at the docs of your backend if it provides something for this. If not, reshaping to a matrix (collapse the middle dimensions into one) and afterwards restoring the original shape should work.